# Как положть []uint в redis

Tags: golang, redis, типы

Пишу код и появилась необходимость записать []uint в redis и потом получать его оттуда.

Но тех инструментов что у меня есть`(redis.Get(client *redis.Client)` , `redis.Set(client *redis.Client))` недостаточно так как они работают только со строками.

Как записать в redis данные типа []uint , если потом нужно доставать именно []uint и отдавать его в ответе пользователю

Можно любые слайсы, не только uint

[Вот весь проект](https://github.com/udonetsm/web-service-gin)

```
func Set(client *redis.Client, key string, value string) error {
    err := client.Set(key, value, 0).Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return err
}

func rClient() *redis.Client {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
    })

    return client
}

func Setting(key string, value string) error {
    return Set(rClient(), key, value)
}
```

А Вот такие данные нужно записать в redis

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Result struct {
    Res []uint `json:"res"`
}

type Values struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
}

func fib(n int) uint {
    var a, b uint = 1, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        a, b = b, a+b
    }
    return a
}

type fibfunc func(int) uint

func ReturnSlce(fib fibfunc, a, b int) []uint {
    slc := make([]uint, 0, b-a+1)
    for i := a; i < b; i++ {
        slc = append(slc, fib(i))
    }
    return slc
}

func postValues(c *gin.Context) {
    var vals Values
    c.BindJSON(&vals)
    var res = Result{
        Res: ReturnSlce(fib, vals.A, vals.B), //res.Res нужно записать в redis
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, res)
}
```

Все что мне пришло на ум, это использовать имеющиеся у меня инструменты работы с redis и каждый элемент uint приводить к string и итерировать в переменную string. Потом эту переменную string класть в redis и когда нужно доставать оттуда. Нет ниакаой трубности пложить туда строку, но когда я ее оттуда достаю, то плучаю кашу в выводе и невозможно больше использоваться как int или uint

Comment: Сконвертируйте ваш массив в JSON перед Set. После Get преобразуйте строку из JSON обратно в массив целых чисел.

Comment: @PakUula попробую сегодня

Comment: @PakUula буду признателен если глянете так ли я понял кэширование и правильно ли его реализовал с redis. Из-за простоты кажется что что-то не так))) Ссылка на репозиторий с решением в моем ответе на мой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

по итогу сделал как предложил Pak Uula.
Код залил в репозиторий. Все получилось и сервер отвечает на запросы из кэша.
Чтобы не засорять здесь вопрос букавами предлагаю посмотреть [мой репозиторий](https://github.com/udonetsm/web-service-gin). Если такое решение подходит для кэширования, прошу вас написать под ответом свое мнение и я отмечу вопрос как верный.

Если вы видите что я неправильно понял кэш и то что я сделал это не кэширование, то, пожалуйста напишите мне, я исправлю код. Я только сейчас изучаю работу с redis и мог что-то не так понять.

Если что то не так то пинайте